# Determine RAID level in Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, dell

On a Windows 2003 server with a Dell PERC 6/i is it possible somewhere to tell what level of RAID the system is currently running from within Windows ( Without rebooting the server ) ..

Under Computer Management-->Device Manager the only info under Disk Drives reads:

```
DELL PERC 6/i SCSI Disk Drive
```

Disk Management just lists the 3 drives in the RAID as Disk 0

Comment: Do you have the OpenManage software installed? That will tell you about the RAID array configuration.

Comment: No I don't...But thanks for the tip -- I just went through the box of crap I have from this install I did about 3 years ago... and there in shrinkwap is the Dell Open Manage DVD...I assume I can install this after the fact safely?

Comment: Yes you can. You can also download the latest version from the Drivers and Downloads section of Dell's support site. DOMSA will show how the disk arrays are configured, whereas Windows won't. http://support.us.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R252582&formatcnt=0&libid=0&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=369525

Comment: You should post in the answers section so we have something to vote up. :)